# Trazer selected com base em valores do banco de dados

Tags: php, option

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho uma tela de cadastro de funcionário, quando vou editar uma pessoa não consigo trazer setada a opção que está cadastrada la no banco.

obs. as options vem do banco e não do formulário html.

por exemplo tenho uma pessoa que está cadastrado como "vendas" mais quando vou editar ela lista como "contabilidade" que seria o primeiro registro da minha tabela local.

código:

```html
 <tr>
      <td align="right"><label for="txtColaborador_local">Local:&nbsp</label></td>
      <td align="left">
      <select class="form-control" name="local_id" required="required" value="<?php echo $row['local']; ?>">
      <?php while($local = mysql_fetch_array($query_local)) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $local['local_id'] ?>"><?php echo $local['nome'] ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
      </select> 
      </td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce quer trazer selecionada a opção que está cadastrada?

E que tabela esta cadastrada isso? nos de mais informações sobre a tabela... Mas pelo que entendi, a lógica seria voce fazer algo desse tipo:

```
    <option <?php if($dadosEdit[$campo[$n]]==$opcao[0]){ echo "selected";} ?> 
value="<?php echo $opcao[0] ?>"><?php echo $opcao[1]; ?></option>
```